# if-else condition for the objective variable using big M notation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, reference-request, linearization, big-m

Let $0\leq \beta\leq 1$ be an objective variable. The size of $\beta$ is $N\!\times\!N$.

Now, how can I impose the following?

> if $\beta_{i,j}>0$ then $\beta_{j,i}=0$

Big M notation can be one of the possible ways, however, I am unable to proceed.

[[post in CVX forum](http://ask.cvxr.com/t/how-to-add-if-else-condition-for-the-objective-variable/7127)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Introduce binary variable $x_{i,j}$ to indicate whether $\beta_{i,j}>0$ and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\beta_{i,j} &\le x_{i,j}\\
x_{i,j} + x_{j,i} &\le 1
\end{align}
(The big-M here is 1.)

The first constraint enforces
$$\beta_{i,j}>0 \implies x_{i,j} = 1.$$
The second constraint enforces
$$x_{i,j} = 1 \implies x_{j,i} = 0.$$
The first constraint enforces
$$x_{j,i} = 0 \implies \beta_{j,i} \le 0.$$
The lower bound on $\beta$ enforces
$$\beta_{j,i} \le 0 \implies \beta_{j,i} = 0.$$
So
$$\beta_{i,j}>0 \implies \beta_{j,i} = 0,$$
as desired.